# Error :- Android resource linking failed, how fix this?

Tags: android, android-studio

While my app building i got this error. how fix this?

```
Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\Dasun Tharanga\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\e51dea7aad9fc20032a5d423af4d220f\res\layout\preference_widget_seekbar.xml:27: warn: generated id 'android:id/icon' for external package 'android'.
C:\Users\Dasun Tharanga\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\e51dea7aad9fc20032a5d423af4d220f\res\layout\preference_widget_seekbar.xml:53: warn: generated id 'android:id/summary' for external package 'android'.
C:\Users\Dasun Tharanga\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\e51dea7aad9fc20032a5d423af4d220f\res\layout\preference_widget_seekbar.xml:45: warn: generated id 'android:id/title' for external package 'android'.
warn: removing resource com.slstudio.ecommerce:string/com_facebook_loginview_logged_in_using_facebook_f1gender without required default value.
D:\Android\Codecanyon\codecanyon-20952416-android-ecommerce-universal-android-ecommerce-store-full-mobile-app-with-laravel-cms\Android App Source Code\ecommerce\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2787: error: style attribute 'attr/colorError (aka com.slstudio.ecommerce:attr/colorError)' not found.
error: failed linking references.
```

Comment: whats your compileSdkVersion?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 26

Comment: try invalidate cache and restart android studio

Comment: @Rishv Singla after delete cahes i got this error  again

Answer (score 0):

Thats is Bug in SDK version 26

Update the SDK version in app build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
```

Comment: clean and rebuild the projects and invalidate catches also

Comment: C:\Users\<user name>\.gradle\caches want to delete this folder?

Comment: In android studio go to file-> invalidate caches/restart

Comment: Can you drop your whatsapp number or messenger username?

Comment: after  invalidate caches/restart  i got another error

Answer (score 0):

After  invalidate caches/restart i got this error

> Blockquote
>   Android resource linking failed
>   warn: removing resource com.slstudio.ecommerce:string/com_facebook_loginview_logged_in_using_facebook_f1gender without required default value.
>   \?\D:\Android\Codecanyon\codecanyon-20952416-android-ecommerce-universal-android-ecommerce-store-full-mobile-app-with-laravel-cms\Android App Source Code\ecommerce\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
>   \?\D:\Android\Codecanyon\codecanyon-20952416-android-ecommerce-universal-android-ecommerce-store-full-mobile-app-with-laravel-cms\Android App Source Code\ecommerce\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
>   D:\Android\Codecanyon\codecanyon-20952416-android-ecommerce-universal-android-ecommerce-store-full-mobile-app-with-laravel-cms\Android App Source Code\ecommerce\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:5101: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>   D:\Android\Codecanyon\codecanyon-20952416-android-ecommerce-universal-android-ecommerce-store-full-mobile-app-with-laravel-cms\Android App Source Code\ecommerce\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:5102: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
>   error: failed linking references.
>   Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

Try it in your dependences:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
    resolutionStrategy.force 'androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0'
    resolutionStrategy.force 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0'
    resolutionStrategy.force 'androidx.fragment:fragment-animated:1.1.0-alpha04'
    resolutionStrategy.force 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
}
```

Comment: Try to clean , and sync gradles

Comment: Try it: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4' check your gradle and download this one

Comment: Can you ping me your free time?

Comment: Thank you very much!! i am waiting for you. In your free time comment to this post i'll give you access in my PC

Comment: Try it : resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0' below the lanes in configurations.all clean and sync gradles

Comment: I just shutdown my PC we will discuss via teamviewer 

Comment: Nice! See you later

Comment: Hey are you free now? Can you help me?

Comment: Hey! Sorry! I forgot completly! I'm in vacations so If you want I can give you my email and talk there. Because I can't connect to much time. I would lole to solve your problem!

Comment: Ok give me your email

Comment: I will wait for your status!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by doing the following:

1. Go to Assets/AndroidServicesResolver/Android/ForceResolve
2. Once resolution is done, remove all duplicate aar files.
3. Now build.